# As do conditions TRUE with if

Tags: php

hi everybody i have the problem with do a conditions I want to make a response with ECHO 
this is i want to communicate to the machine

```html
if(isset($_SESSION['confirmar_imagen']) ==true ) {
 echo 'cambio la imagen con exito <font color="blue">'.$_SESSION["nick"].'</font></b><br>';
 echo "<a href='../../funciones/editar_user/index.php'>Regresar</a><br>";
 //borrar variabel sesion para que no regresen con el mismo valor 
 unset($_SESSION['confirmar_iamgen']); 

}


if(isset($_SESSION['confirmar_text']) ==true ){
  echo 'cambio de nombre por <font color="blue">'.$_SESSION["nick"].'</font></b><br> ' ;
 echo 'cambio de pass por  <font color="blue">'.$_SESSION["pass"].'</font></b><br> ' ;
 echo "<a href='../../funciones/editar_user/index.php'>Regresar</a><br>";
 unset($_SESSION['confirmar_text']);
}
```

the problem is once i send the information to the the file contend this code the machine ride the first good only show me the content the $_SESSION['confirmar_imagen'] but when send the information to the second the code imprint the $_SESSION['confirmar_imagen'] and $_SESSION['confirmar_text']

I have one code before run this code is  like

```html
//esta sesion esta creada para reconocer que entro a la pagina sirve para que no entren a la confirmacion si pasa por aqui 
 $entrar="entrar2";
 $_SESSION['entrar'] = $entrar;
 // sesion creada para visualizar texto en confirmacion.php
 $_SESSION['confirmar_text'] = $entrar;
 //entra a la pagian confirmar 
 header("location: confirmacion.php");
```

what is the problem sorry for my writer i dont really speak English

Comment: `if(isset($_SESSION['confirmar_imagen']) ==true )` that will give you a false positive and isn't the way to do that, you need 2 separate conditions, same for the other one

Comment: start by changing `if(isset($_SESSION['confirmar_imagen']) ==true ) {` to `if(isset($_SESSION['confirmar_imagen']) ) {` . When you ask a question about an error, ***ALWAYS***, post the error log. To enable error reporting to your php code append `error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', '1');` at the top of your script, what does it return ?

Comment: Fred i did that look the code up if(isset($_SESSION['confirmar_imagen']) ==true )  and if(isset($_SESSION['confirmar_text']) ==true )

Comment: Pedro i put the code you gave me i put this up the script like this error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', '1'); if(isset($_SESSION['confirmar_imagen'])) { if($_SESSION['confirmar_imagen'] == true) { ... ALL CODE I don't know if i use that righ? dont back error

Comment: OH MY GOOD READY in my   first uset i have wrong the array i wrote ['confirmar_iamgen'] and the right is ['confirmar_imagen'] thank for you post